# declare class with if condition

Tags: c#, class

I have a class and I need to declare a few members of the class based on an if condition.

How can I do this?

```
Class transport(bool two_wheel=true)
{

   string car,

   string bus,

   if ( two_wheel=true)

   {

     string bike,

     string cycle

   }

};
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you're actually trying to achieve. The code you've got is certainly not viable, but it sounds like you *might* want a `Transport` abstract base class with some subclasses... but it's not clear why you'd want different string fields...

Comment: Although it's not clear what and why. As a high abstraction level design: A class transport has one string `string description` and a `int count` for wheels. Cars have `car` as description and `4` as wheels count, bikes have `bike` and `2`.. etc. You send these as parameters once you create your `transport` instances. Then, you do whatever you want using the other functions. If two wheels, you know what to do, else, etc.

Comment: Why does your class `transport` which is a high level of abstraction depend on more concrete things, like 'car', 'cycle' etc? Also, why does it depend on all of it's children? You have to re-model your abstraction - probably by having just wheels count and description fields.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having a problem in understanding your class design. This should help you approach a good one:

As a high abstraction level design: A class `transport` has one string `string description` and an `int count` for wheels number. Cars have `car` as description and `4` as wheels count, bikes have `bike` and `2`.. etc. You send these as parameters once you create your `transport` instances. Then, you do whatever you want using the other functions. If two wheels, you know what to do, else, etc.

Example:

```
class transport
{
private:
    std::string description;
    int WheelsCount;

public:
    transport() { this->description = "Default"; this->WheelsCount = 0; } // default constructor
    transport(std::string _description, int _WheelsCount) { this->description = _description; this->WheelsCount = _WheelsCount; }
    // ..
    // accessors here (getters and setters)
    // ..
    void MyFunction()
    {
        if (this->WheelsCount == 4)
        {
            //then it's a car, bus
            std::cout << "Description from within your condition: " << this->description << '\n'; // do your desired task
        }
        else
        {
            // it's a bike or a cycle
            std::cout << "Description from within your condition: "<< this->description << '\n'; // do the other task
        }
    }
};
```

Now `include <iostream>`,`<string>` and use the below `main()`, to have some fun:

```
int main()
{
    transport bike("Bike", 2); // create a bike
    transport car("Car", 4); // create a car

    bike.MyFunction();
    car.MyFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]